# how AccumulatedGrad object's register_hook works?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

```
class FFN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FFN,self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(4,20,bias=True)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(20,4,bias=True)

    def forward(self,input):
        x = self.linear1(input)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        return x

class ParamState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stream = None

class ParamHandle:
    def __init__(self,params:list[nn.Parameter],module:nn.Module):
        self.params = params
        self.module = module
        self.hook_handle = []


def get_handle(model:nn.Module):
    tmp_list = []
    for parameter in model.parameters():
        tmp_list.append(parameter)
    handle = ParamHandle(tmp_list,model)
    return handle

def my_hook(handle:ParamHandle,*unused):
    print(handle.params[0].grad)

def pre_forward_hook(handle:ParamHandle,*unused):
    print("pre_forward_hook")
    param = handle.params[0]
    tmp_p = param.expand_as(param)
    grad_acc = tmp_p.grad_fn.next_functions[0][0]
    grad_acc.register_hook(functools.partial(my_hook,handle))

def flatten_param(params:list[nn.Parameter]):
    flatted_param = torch.cat([p.flatten() for p in params])
    return flatted_param

model = FFN()
handle = get_handle(model)
register_pre_forward_hook(handle)
```

if I don't invoke function flatten_param(), then my_hook function will not be invoked

```
f = flatten_param(handle.params)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

dummy_input = torch.randn(4)
labels = torch.randint(4,(4,)).float()

output = model(dummy_input)
loss = criterion(output,labels)

loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

I want register AccumulatedGrad object hook, but the hook cannot be invoke util I use the following function before the backward():

I want register AccumulatedGrad object hook, but the hook cannot be invoke util I use the following function before the backward():

I want register AccumulatedGrad object hook, but the hook cannot be invoke util I use the following function before the backward():

I want register AccumulatedGrad object hook, but the hook cannot be invoke util I use the following function before the backward():

I want register AccumulatedGrad object hook, but the hook cannot be invoke util I use the following function before the backward():

```
def flatten_param(params:list[nn.Parameter]):
    flatted_param = torch.cat([p.flatten() for p in params])
    return flatted_param
```

Comment: there are many undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)